# Une chose peut-elle jouer le rôle de quelque chose d’autre?

Tags: choix-de-mot, formulation, reformulation

Exemple:

Ce tableau joue le rôle d’une décoration.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Oui. Quelques exemples :

> Le sang qui coule […] joue le rôle d'une décoration. [Jocelyne Peigney. La Blessure de Ménélas et la bossette de Mors (Illiade IV, 141–147) : quelques remarques. In *Troïka: parcours antiques : mélanges offerts à Michel Woronoff*, 2007. p. 102.](https://www.google.fr/books/edition/Tro%C3%AFka/nLiUt1QoEB8C?hl=en&gbpv=1&dq=%22joue+le+r%C3%B4le+d%27une+d%C3%A9coration%22&pg=PA102&printsec=frontcover)

> Le panneau treillis […] joue le rôle d’une décoration bucolique plutôt fleurie [DecorAttitude, « Aménager un jardin avec une clôture ». 2021.](https://www.decorattitude.com/amenager-un-jardin-avec-une-cloture/)

« Jouer le rôle de », dans ce contexte, a à peu près le même sens que « servir de », qui est plus courant. Il y a une légère nuance : « A sert de B » implique que A n'est pas naturellement un B, alors que « A joue le rôle de B » ou « A joue le rôle d'un(e) B » ne l'implique pas forcément.